# The smart pointer (specifically shared_ptr) doesn't act like I expected, how to fix it (elegantly)

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Lately I'm working on a project that use raw pointers in some places in code, everything seems fine and I want to upgrade my code by using smart pointers just for safety like everyone says, but it turns out the wrong results.

I was looking for the bug for hours until I realized this fatal inconvenience of `shared_ptr` that I will just only summarize that in this little experiement showed below.

This is the experiment code:

```
int main() {
    // code 1
    int arr[5] = { 1, 5, 6, 7, 9 };
    cout << &arr[2] << endl;
    shared_ptr ptr = make_shared<int>(arr[2]);
    cout << ptr << "\n";

    // code 2
    cout << &arr[2] << endl;
    int* ptr1 = &arr[2];
    cout << ptr1 << "\n";
}
```

Basically, what I'm doing here is that I want a pointer that points to an element in the array (my project uses vector, but this experiment uses array still gives the same issue) contains the same address of that element, for example in `//code 2` (old method using raw pointer) those 2 `cout` commands will give the same result, but not for `//code 1` when it just prints out 2 separate addresses.

After debugging for about half a minute, I realized that this line `make_shared<int>(arr[2])` in `code 1` will create the poniter that **points to an address that has the same value as the element in the array but not points to the element in the array**, which is quite inconvenient because I was expecting it to act like `code 2`.

additional info: When I asks chatgpt will the code 1 give the same result, it answers "yes", which proves that this problem is not as obvious for many people.

By the way, any suggest for fix? Thank you.

Comment: `shared_ptr` isn't supposed to replace all raw pointers, it's only for replacing *owning* raw pointers (those for which you would otherwise have to remember to call `delete`). Since `&arr[2]` is non-owning, replacing it with `shared_ptr` makes no sense.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you have? Why do you want a smart pointer to an array element? And you should look at the smart pointers more in terms of *ownership*.

Comment: And, as you noticed, ChatGTP (and other similar so-called AI systems) are not reliable. Asking code-related questions usually takes a few attempts, telling it about errors it made. It really require one to be a good and experienced programmer to begin with.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "*shared_ptr isn't supposed to replace all raw pointers, it's only for replacing owning raw pointers*", perhaps I forgot about it, thanks for reminding, looks like my project only needs pointers pointing to other stack-values so there's no need for deallocate the memory

Comment: When changing raw pointers to smart pointers you first have to have a very clear understanding of ownership. In most cases you can leave the raw pointers in place if the pointers are non-owning. In the other cases you should try std::unique_ptr first. And in a lot of places you should just replace dynamically allocated arrays with `std::vector`.  The last thing you should do is blindly add shared_ptr to everything. Last note for arrays there is `std::array` which allows you to return arrays from functions without pointers at all

Comment: I would also recommend a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `template <typename T> using view_ptr = T*;` Then `view_ptr<int> ptr1{ &arr[2] };` and now your code is self documenting that `ptr1` is intentionally a non-owning pointer.

Comment: @Eljay at this point,  this is no different than raw pointer pointing to other variable's address LOL

Comment: That is correct.  The **only** difference is that the `view_ptr` makes the code self-documenting for the intent.  A raw pointer does not — unless the code consistently uses a policy that raw pointers are non-owning pointers, and owning pointers are smart pointers.  That requires discipline, and all the devs on the team being on the same page for that convention.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: @Eljay I mean I can still use raw pointer with the name "view_ptr" with proper comment right beside it for documentation, there's no need for using template for such trivial thing